# Are there any ways to install a third party keyboard as the system keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, encryption, system-apps

I am wondering if it is possible to install a new keyboard as the system keyboard. I'd like to do this because I want to use an open-source keyboard (Like AnysoftKeyboard) for typing my encryption password at boot. From what I've read, only the system keyboard is available for use when entering the encryption password.

My phone is rooted, I have adb, and I have a terminal emulator on the phone that can su. If it's possible to do, what is the process? (If it's relevant, my phone is a Galaxy S7)

Comment: I haven't tried this but you could use Titanium Backup or other apps to first 1. Convert your system keyboard to user keyboard and then 2. Convert your installed keyboard to System keyboard. Reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way1: famous method now a days.

1. Unroot
2. Install Magisk (a systemless root solution) [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/official-magisk-v7-universal-systemless-t3473445)
3. Install App Systemizer module for Magisk from magisk app
4. Make your app system app

This way you can make the user-installed app a system app without actually modifying the /system partition.

Way2:

Change system partition evergreen method
Follow this guide [link](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/)

Comment: link for magisk systemizer module [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-app-systemizer-t3477512)